# Set cookies in cowboy properly

Tags: cookies, erlang, cowboy

it's pretty simple to set cookies in cowboy 
https://ninenines.eu/docs/en/cowboy/2.0/guide/cookies/

however when I set cookies using this method

```
init(Req0, Opts) ->     
    Method = cowboy_req:method(Req0),   
    {ok, Body0,    _} = cowboy_req:read_urlencoded_body(Req0), 
    {ok, RiakPid} = riakc_pb_socket:start("127.0.0.1", 8087), 
    Req = handle(Method,    Body0, Req0, RiakPid),     
    {ok, Body, _} = cowboy_req:read_body(Req),  
    erlang:display(Req), %    here I also check request    
    {ok,Req, Opts}.

% post
handle(<<"POST">>, Body, Req0, RiakPid) ->
    SessionID = "blablabla",
    Req = cowboy_req:set_resp_cookie(<<"token">>, SessionID, Req0),
    erlang:display(Req) %here I check request
    Req;

% get. Here I should successfully get token in cookies
handle(<<"GET">>, Body, Req0, RiakPid) ->   
    Cookies = cowboy_req:parse_cookies(Req0),   
    {_, Token} = lists:keyfind(<<"token">>, 1, Cookies), % here is when i fail to get    cookie by key     
    erlang:display(Token), 
    Req0;
```

and get Request using `erlang:display(Req)` :

```
headers=>#{
<<"accept">>=><<"*/*">>
<<"accept-encoding">>=><<"gzip, deflate, br">>
<<"accept-language">>=><<"en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6">>
<<"connection">>=><<"keep-alive">>
<<"content-length">>=><<"24">>
<<"content-type">>=><<"application/x-www-form-urlencoded">>
<<"cookie">>=><<"user=\"2|1:0|10:1487346656|4:user|4:Mw==|ba24da6f51c92ad05e278f218d15d2cda8ed9e7e3b800dcf39a244de5ecfff37\"">>
<<"host">>=><<"localhost:2939">>
<<"origin">>=><<"chrome-extension://eelcnbccaccipfolokglfhhmapdchbfg">>
<<"user-agent">>=><<"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36">>}
host=><<"localhost">>
host_info=>undefined,method=><<"POST">>
path=><<"/login">>
path_info=>undefined
peer=>{{127,0,0,1},53362}
pid=><0.4104.0>,port=>2939,qs=><<>>
ref=>my_http_listener
resp_cookies=>#{<<"token">>=>[<<"token">>,<<"=">>,"blablabla",<<"; Version=1">>,<<>>,<<>>,<<>>,<<>>,<<>>]}
scheme=><<"http">>,streamid=>1,version=>'HTTP/1.1'}
```

So I'm settings headers, not the cookies.

How to set real cookies?

to be smth like

```
<<"cookie">>=>
<<"user=\"2|1:0|10:1487346656|4:user|4:Mw==|ba24da6f51c92ad05e278f218d15d2cda8ed9e7e3b800dcf39a244de5ecfff37\"">>
<<"token=\"blablabla\"">>
```

Comment: Doesn't the line `resp_cookies=>#{<<"token">>=>[<<"token">>,<<"=">>,"blablabla",<<"; Version=1">>,<<>>,<<>>,<<>>,<<>>,<<>>]}` in your `erlang:display(Req)`indicate that you are setting that cookie?

Comment: as I understand i settings the header. And also when i do `cowboy_req:parse_cookies(Req)` i get only `<<"user=\"2|1:0|10:1487346656|4:user|4:Mw==|ba24da6f51c92ad05e278f218d15d2cda8ed9e7e3b800dcf39a244de5ecfff37\"">>`

Comment: Can we have a complete example code where you set the cookie and where you try to retrieve it?

Comment: I have edit a bit question to show part of my code. Don't pay attention to Riak

Answer (score 0):

Here is correct code

```
% post
handle(<<"POST">>, Body, Req0, RiakPid) ->
    SessionID = "blablabla",
    Req1 = cowboy_req:set_resp_cookie(<<"token">>, SessionID, Req0),
    erlang:display(Req1) %here I check request
    Req = cowboy_req:reply(200, Req1), % We should always pass correct Request
    Req;
```

Whats the point is: When one works with Request he should also pay attention of the Request and the status of it. When you end Request (Req = cowboy_req:reply(200, Req1)) your resp_cookies records pass to the cookies. Otherwise the Request is incomplete